# Add shadow at bottom of UIview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Actually, I want shadow at bottom of UIView.
I had tried some code but getting shadow from top side only and I am using swift 3 currently.

Please follow below code :

```
        let horizontalLine = UIView()
        horizontalLine.frame = CGRect.zero
        horizontalLine.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        self.addSubview(horizontalLine)

        horizontalLine.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        horizontalLine.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        horizontalLine.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        horizontalLine.layer.masksToBounds = false
        horizontalLine.backgroundColor = .lightGray
       horizontalLine.layer.shadowRadius = 5
```

Also I am using snapkit library for UI Setting:

```
        horizontalLine.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(5)
            make.width.equalTo(self.snp.width)
            make.left.equalTo(self.snp.left)
            make.right.equalTo(self.snp.right)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.snp.bottom)
        }
```

How it looks now:
[image]

Also, I do have collection view just down that.
And we have one more collection view just backside of that line.

Please guide me guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change offset as (0,0) and try

Comment: niks -- show an image of what you're getting now, and how you *want* it to look. Based on your code, it appears you are adding `horizontalLine` view as a subview of another view, but then constraining `horizontalLine` to all 4 sides... which means the "other view" is completely hidden by `horizontalLine`? Any reason you don't just add the shadow layer to the "other view"? Or just use `horizontalLine` on its own?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I tried it but not working shadow appearing at top

Comment: @DonMag I have updated please check it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image you show, it looks like the "shadow" you are seeing is in the cell content of the collection view *above* your `horizontalLine` view.

It also looks like the shadow on your `horizontalLine` view is not visible at all - because its superview is clipping it.

Try this:

```
    // new line
    self.clipsToBounds = false
    // rest of your code...
    let horizontalLine = UIView()
```

Comment: Yup, there was a problem with the super view. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

**try this..**

```
let horizontalLine = UIView()
horizontalLine.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 350, width: 150, height: 150)
horizontalLine.backgroundColor = .lightGray
self.view.addSubview(horizontalLine)

horizontalLine.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
horizontalLine.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
horizontalLine.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
horizontalLine.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
horizontalLine.layer.masksToBounds = false
horizontalLine.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
```

Comment: There was just super view error. Thank you for your help. Also, your example is working as expected.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Any comment on why downwoting this answer? It works for me.